Docker jenkins setup - CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG invalid path
See repo:
https://github.com/inspiraller/docker-jenkins-24
docker run --name docker-jenkins --rm --env JENKINS_ADMIN_ID=admin --env CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG="/var/jenkins_conf" \
-v /${PWD}/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /${PWD}/.casc_configs:/var/jenkins_conf -v /${PWD}/.secrets:/run/secrets:ro -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000  docker-jenkins:1

This gives me an error

2024-08-21 16:33:39.045+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  hudson.util.BootFailure#publish: Failed to initialize Jenkins
io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfiguratorException: Invalid configuration: 'C:/Program Files/Git/var/jenkins_conf' isn't a valid path.
at PluginClassLoader for configuration-as-code//io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configs(ConfigurationAsCode.java:728

The equivalent environment variable in docker-compose is exactly the same and it works:
    environment:
      - CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG=/var/jenkins_conf

Not sure why there is a difference in the operation of docker-compose v docker run.

Do you really need the slashs at the beginning of your paths ?
-v ${PWD}/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
-v ${PWD}/.casc_configs:/var/jenkins_conf
-v ${PWD}/.secrets:/run/secrets:ro

@YassineLbk - yes if using windows. In any case this doesn't solve the problem changing it. The volume is correctly mounted.
